# Why use code A when code B works perfectly it seems?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have just started learning to code.

[image: Code A and B]

Code B does not use Document.selectSomething per say and yet works, it seems to me the id of an element can be used directly to add event listeners without having to document select the element then adding event listeners

Comment: You didn't ask a question

Comment: Don't just describe code, post code. (with description)

Comment: @Luca Actually there is a `?` in the title, just extremely unclear.

Comment: Don't post image of code without the code itself.

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how it's possible that taking a screenshot of code and uploading it to the Internet is somehow easier than copy-pasting the code as text.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you try to access a `DOM` element directly will give you an error if the element doesn't exist. But accessing it through `getElementById` selector will return `null`. 
And because elements with an id which contains dashes like `'my-id'` can't be accessed directly.

Comment: thanks for answering, but actually both code B and Code A work with no errors generated anywhere in the console

Comment: you can with bracket notation off window.... https://jsfiddle.net/pn10gx4f/

Comment: @epascarello Yep, I know, but I thought by directly he was refering to exactly the way he shows in his examples

Comment: @Mohamed Jadib I was answering your question 'Why use code A when code B works perfectly it seems?'. In your example it works because the id exists in your DOM, this is not about it working or not, (although I told you the difference of giving an error vs returning null) it's about using best practices.

Comment: @Kronen I read more about it and I get it now, it is about best practices